# LNK2019 while compiling Agora.IO windows sample

Tags: lnk2019, agora.io

I'm getting LNK2019 error while compiling Agora.io samples (https://docs.agora.io/en/Agora%20Platform/downloads)

Which library should I include to the project and in what way?

[The lnk2019 error in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irrlq.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Video SDK Windows(x86) v3.0.0

(x64 version of sdk is not working for this sample)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer has been flagged for review since you are a new contributor. It looks like you're providing useful information, but both the question and the answer are quiet terse. Please add more information (such as links to documentation) and improve the question so that it explains the context  of the problem better. The goal here is to help others with the same or similar problems find this anwer and benefit from it as well.